# Удаление элемента в RecyclerView из другого Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

У меня открывается `activity` по клику элемента из `RecyclerView` в это время `RecyclerView` становится на паузу. После удаления элемента из `activity` по возвращению в `RecyclerView` он не пропадает, но после уничтожения и нового запуска элемент исчезает. В `onResume()` прописывал `notifyDataSetChanged()` но безрезультатно.

Код adapter'a:

```
var items: ArrayList<FavQuote> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return FavQuoteViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_favs, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is FavQuoteViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(items[position])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    class FavQuoteViewHolder
    constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private val quote: TextView = itemView.quote
        private val quoteAuthor: TextView = itemView.quote_author
        private val selectQuote: Button = itemView.select_quote
        private val mActivity = itemView.context as Activity
        private val intent = Intent(mActivity, QuoteSelected::class.java)

        fun bind(favQuote: FavQuote) {
            quote.text = favQuote.quote
            quoteAuthor.text = favQuote.author
            selectQuote.setOnClickListener {
                intent.putExtra("quote", favQuote.quote)
                intent.putExtra("author", favQuote.author)
                intent.putExtra("id", favQuote.id)
                mActivity.startActivity(intent)
                mActivity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
            }
        }
    }

    fun submitQuoteInfo(quote: String, author: String, id: Int) {
        val element = FavQuote(quote, author, id)
        if (items.contains(element)) {
            return
        } else {
            items.add(element)
            notifyItemInserted(items.indexOf(element))
        }
    }
```

Так же пробовал решение, описанное [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551642/how-update-an-activity-on-onresume). Результата нет.

Так же попробовал добавить метод удаления элемента в Adapter'e, но результата так же нет:

```
fun removeElement(element: FavQuote) {
        items.remove(element)
        notifyItemRemoved(items.indexOf(element))
    }
```

Comment: Вы в адаптер не передаете новый массив данных, поэтому изменений и нет. Сделайте в адаптере метод, например, по приему новых данных.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, добавил метод, но так же безрезультатно.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, новый массив передавать нецелесообразно, ведь нужно убрать всего один элемент. Это займёт много времени.

Comment: Если проблема не решилась, то делайте логирование действий, где-то что-то не то удаляете возможно.